# WCF test Client working on my ip but do not work on the other ip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, wcf-client, wcfserviceclient

I have created WCF test client, and it's working on my IP. however, when I tried to test it on the guest's IP it was not working. See an error message below:

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

[image: exception screenshot]

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: which .NET framework you are using? Also, try enabling TLS1.2 for services call. You may need to write System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; before the service call.

Comment: Could you speak more specific ?  @Nirman! thanks

Answer (score 0):

While using WCF service you have to host it on the server then you can access it to another system or computer please check hosting steps for WCF in order to complete your process.

Check this links : [WCF Hosting Steps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/hosting-wcf-service-inside-iis/)

Here we have the same question discussion : [Failed to invoke the service](https://forums.asp.net/t/2016601.aspx?wcf%20test%20client%20failed%20to%20invoke%20the%20service)